# How to change a type in an expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method like this:

```
private bool Method_1(Expression<Func<IPerson, bool>> expression)
{
    /* Some code that will call Method_2 */
}
```

In this method I want to change the `IPerson` type to another type. I want to call another method that looks like this:

```
private bool Method_2(Expression<Func<PersonData, bool>> expression)
{
    /* Some code */
}
```

So, in `method_1` I need to change `IPerson` to `PersonData`. How can I do this?

Edit:

When I call: `Method_1(p => p.Id == 1)` I want to 'save' the condition (`p.Id == 1`) but I want to execute this condition on another type, namely `IPerson`. So, I need to alter the expression or create a new expression with `IPerson`

Comment: is there a relation between `IPerson` and `PersonData`?

Comment: @w0lf No, they don't know each other. `PersonData` is the DTO version of the interface (`IPerson`).

Comment: I don't see how that could be done. Can you post an example of how a concrete expression would look like and how would you transform it to use `PersonData` if you could do it manually?

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is easy if you use .net 4 (update: as noted in comment `ExpressionVisitor` was added in version 4 not 4.5) it would require some googling for older frameworks:

There are some assumptions but I think they are valid for your DTO and Entity scenario - properties accessed must match.

```
class PersonData
{
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}

interface IPerson 
{
    bool Prop { get; set; }
}
```

In .net 4 there is `ExpressionVisitor` class defined that makes this a lot easier if you use older one then you need to write or find implementation of it:

```
class Visitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ParameterExpression _parameter;

    //there must be only one instance of parameter expression for each parameter 
    //there is one so one passed here
    public Visitor(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    //this method replaces original parameter with given in constructor
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameter;
    }

    //this one is required because PersonData does not implement IPerson and it finds
    //property in PersonData with the same name as the one referenced in expression 
    //and declared on IPerson
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        //only properties are allowed if you use fields then you need to extend
        // this method to handle them
        if (node.Member.MemberType != System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        //name of a member referenced in original expression in your 
        //sample Id in mine Prop
        var memberName = node.Member.Name;
        //find property on type T (=PersonData) by name
        var otherMember = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberName);
        //visit left side of this expression p.Id this would be p
        var inner = Visit(node.Expression);
        return Expression.Property(inner, otherMember);
    }
}
```

Proof of concept:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main()
    {
        //sample expression
        Expression<Func<IPerson, bool>> expression = x => x.Prop;

        //parameter that will be used in generated expression
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PersonData));
        //visiting body of original expression that gives us body of the new expression
        var body = new Visitor<PersonData>(param).Visit(expression.Body);
        //generating lambda expression form body and parameter 
        //notice that this is what you need to invoke the Method_2
        Expression<Func<PersonData, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<PersonData, bool>>(body, param);
        //compilation and execution of generated method just to prove that it works
        var boolValue = lambda.Compile()(new PersonData());
    }
}
```

Note that this will work for simple expressions. If you need to handle `x.Prop.Prop1 < 3` then you need to extend this further.

Comment: Thank you. Is it too much to ask if you could provide some comment in the code? I find it difficult to understand since expression (trees?) are not really my field of expertise...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I almost don't dare to ask, but could you also provide the Main app with comments?

Comment: Thanks a lot - again. I'm struggling with Fields now. Apperently, the lambda works with fields. Don't know why, but I am trying to work that out now :).

Comment: Yes `MemberExpression` will also hold field access but you will need to use `GetField` reflection method instead of `GetProperty` and of course `Expression.Field` instead of `Expression.Property`.

Comment: `ExpressionVisitor` is already in .Net 4.0. For .Net 3.5, you can get it from IQToolkit.

Comment: @Rafal I'm trying to put something up to do this but in cases where there is an expression like x = x.MyProp.Name == "xpto"... Any ideas? Or this is clearly way much work?

Comment: @Stargazer this is the way to go, and it should be straight forward just launch this as is and see what happens.

Comment: @Rafal, I've done exactly that. Take a look to my question, containing code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613749/convert-expression-tree-types).

Besides you say in your answer that to support things like x.Prop.Prop1 < 3 this has to be extended... Is in the "extension" part that I need help. :)

Comment: I've not idea what is going on here, but it works brilliantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement of @Rafal solution. It allows to pipeline property calls of complex objects.

```
//sample expression
Expression<Func<IPerson, bool>> expression = x => x.PropA.PropB.PropC == "ABC";
```

Simply change the `otherMember` to use the type of `inner`.

```
class Visitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ParameterExpression _parameter;

    //there must be only one instance of parameter expression for each parameter 
    //there is one so one passed here
    public Visitor(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    //this method replaces original parameter with given in constructor
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameter;
    }

    //this one is required because PersonData does not implement IPerson and it finds
    //property in PersonData with the same name as the one referenced in expression 
    //and declared on IPerson
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        //only properties are allowed if you use fields then you need to extend
        // this method to handle them
        if (node.Member.MemberType != System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        //name of a member referenced in original expression in your 
        //sample Id in mine Prop
        var memberName = node.Member.Name;
        
        /*Fix*/
        //visit left side of this expression p.Id this would be p
        var inner = Visit(node.Expression);
        //find property on type T (=PersonData) by name
        var otherMember = inner.Type.GetProperty(memberName);

        return Expression.Property(inner, otherMember);
    }
}
```