# Replace a type in an expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I'm struggling with the modification of an expression tree. I've simplified the example to make it easier to display here. Let's start with two classes:

```
    public class Filter
    {
        public string FilterableProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string FilterableProperty2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public string FilterableProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string FilterableProperty2 { get; set; }
        public string NonFilterableProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

All properties in the Filter class also exist in the Entity class. Now I would like to use the Filter class to return the desired entities with a method like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntities(Expression<Func<Filter, bool>> filter)
    {
        Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> convertedFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(
            filter.Body,
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity), filter.Parameters[0].Name));

        using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            return entities.Entities.Where(convertedFilter);
        }
    }
```

So basically I just change the type of the expression parameter. Now when I call the function like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetFilteredEntities()
    {
        return GetEntities(x => x.FilterableProperty1 == "Test");
    }
```

I get an exception saying that the parameter x was not found in the specified query expression. Obviously by replacing the ParameterExpression I am breaking something. How can I create a new expression with the correct type that takes over (or rebuilds) the body of the original expression ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more searching I found the answer here: [How to change a type in an expression tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932779/how-to-change-a-type-in-an-expression-tree). It didn't show up in the suggestions when I submitted my question.

As I don't really need the Filter class, I instead created an interface with only the properties that I want to be able to filter (IEntity) and modified the Entity class to implement it. Now I'm able to get the desired results with this:

```
// Example use: return entities.Entities.Where(ExpressionTransformer<IEntity,Entity>.Transform(filter));
internal static class ExpressionTransformer<TFrom, TTo> where TTo : TFrom
{
    public class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ParameterExpression _parameter;

        public Visitor(ParameterExpression parameter)
        {
            _parameter = parameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return _parameter;
        }
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TTo, bool>> Tranform(Expression<Func<TFrom, bool>> expression)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo));
        Expression body = new Visitor(parameter).Visit(expression.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTo, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }
}
```

In case you need to do something similar but you cannot work with an interface or you cannot make your class implement that interface: the answer is also in the above mentioned answer

Comment: Just a word of caution as I know this is old and probably not monitored but I stumbled upon it.  You need to use the override of the 'VisitMember' as well on your Visitor Class and a generic T.  IF your objects are not set to be inherently the same.  In your example your generics of TTo and TFrom are equivalent.  You can make this work for non equivalent objects that have similar properties with the 'VisitMember'.