# Convert type in Expression<Func<T1, bool>> to Expression<Func<T2, bool>> (LINQ to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq, mapping, expression, func

Note:

1. My app (asp.net mvc) is separated on layers for loose coupling purposes.
2. Entity krt_Naftan and ScrollLineDTO have same property and use in different layers. I use Automapper to convert between them.
3. I would like use some predicate (`x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == '01.01.2016'`) througout LINQ to SQL (Expression tree).

It works for func:

```
Func<ScrollLineDTO, bool> predicate = x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == '01.01.2016';
Func<krt_Naftan, bool> func = x => predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x));
```

Because I can't wrap func to Expression tree (LINQ to SQL)
//doesn't work for EF6

```
Expression<Func<krt_Naftan, bool>> filter = x => func(x);
```

I try convert type in expressions (compile error)

```
Expression<Func<ScrollLineDTO, bool>> predicate = x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == '01.01.2016';

Expression<Func<krt_Naftan, bool>> func = x =>predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x));
```

Question: How can i use convert functionality for expression tree statements? or maybe a need something else;)

1) Index method (UI layer)

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? period = null, int page = 1, bool asService = false, ushort initialSizeItem = 15) {
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        long recordCount;

        //default
        Expression<Func<ScrollLineDTO, bool>> predicate = x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == (period == null ? new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1) : period);

        var result = new IndexMV() {
            ListKrtNaftan = _bussinesEngage.SkipTable(page, initialSizeItem, out recordCount, predicate),
                ...
            }
        };
  ....
```

2)(BLL layer)

```
 public IEnumerable<T> SkipTable<T>(int page, int initialSizeItem, out long recordCount, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) {

            if (predicate == null) {
                //convert func types

                Expression<Func<krt_Naftan, bool>> func = x => predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x));
                //wrap in func to expression (is not impossible, maybe if pass method...)
                //Expression<Func<krt_Naftan, bool>> filter = x => func(x);

                return (IEnumerable<T>)Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ScrollLineDTO>>(Engage.GetSkipRows(page, initialSizeItem, out recordCount, x => x.KEYKRT, func));
            }

            return (IEnumerable<T>)Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ScrollLineDTO>>(Engage.GetSkipRows<krt_Naftan, long>(page, initialSizeItem, out recordCount, x => x.KEYKRT));
        }

/// <summary>
/// Return pagging part of table and general count of rows
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Current enity</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">Type for ordering</typeparam>
/// <param name="page">Number page</param>
/// <param name="size">Count row per one page</param>
/// <param name="recordCount"></param>
/// <param name="orderPredicate">Condition for ordering</param>
/// <param name="filterPredicate">Condition for filtering</param>
/// <param name="caсhe"></param>
/// <returns>Return definition count rows of specific entity</returns>
public IEnumerable<T> GetSkipRows<T, TKey>(int page, int size, out long recordCount, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderPredicate, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterPredicate = null, bool caсhe = false) where T : class {
    recordCount = GetCountRows(filterPredicate);
    using (Uow = new UnitOfWork()) {
        return Uow.Repository<T>().Get_all(filterPredicate, caсhe).OrderByDescending(orderPredicate).Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size).ToList();
    }
}
```

3) (DLL layer) get data from db

```
/// <summary>
            /// Get lazy data set (with cashing or not (attr MergeOption )
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="predicate">filter condition for retrieving data from source(database)</param>
            /// <param name="enableDetectChanges">Compare two snapshot of data (one when retrieve data from database other when call method saveChanges(). If exists some diffrences => generate avaible SQL command</param>
            /// <param name="enableTracking"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public IQueryable<T> Get_all(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, bool enableDetectChanges = true, bool enableTracking = true) {
                /*//sync data in Db & EF (if change not tracking for EF)
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _dbSet.Where(predicate));
                    _context.Entry(_dbSet.Where(predicate)).Reload(); EF 4.1+*/
                ActiveContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = enableDetectChanges;
                if (predicate == null) return (enableTracking) ? _dbSet : _dbSet.AsNoTracking();
                var result = (enableTracking) ? _dbSet.Where(predicate) : _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);

                return result;
            }
```

thx)

Comment: What doesn't work and what are you trying to do? Why are you trying to convert expressions? Linq to SQL may allow expressions that result in loading everything to memory. Linq to EF correctly prevents these and throws an exception.

Comment: Why do you use expressions instead of writing, eg `myQuery=myQuery.Where(x=> x.DTBUHOTCHET == "01.01.2016");` ? It looks like you are trying to create some kind of dynamic criteria, but that can easily be done by using different `Where` statements

Comment: Yes, I have 'general' service for request to Db i use general method (indepedent from type of entity and type of lambda predicate). ie IEnumerable<T> GetSkipRows<T, TKey>(int page, int size, out long recordCount, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderPredicate, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterPredicate = null, bool caсhe = false) where T : class;

Comment: why don't you simply add a call to `.Where()`? Where is the actual data access code and why are you trying to convert between types? Besides, `predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x)` can never be converted to SQL - what *is* the expression there? Where is SQL Server going to find `Mapper.Map`? If this worked with LINQ to SQL, it's because LINQ to SQL loaded all `x`s in memory then applied the predicate to them, resulting in awful performance.

Comment: It works throught Unit of Work pattern

Comment: Which still doesn't explain anything. Post your code

Comment: 1) Index method (UI layer)
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? period = null, int page = 1, bool asService = false, ushort initialSizeItem = 15) {
 if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
  long recordCount;

  //default
  Expression<Func<ScrollLineDTO, bool>> predicate = x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == (period == null ? new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1) : period);

  var result = new IndexMV() {
   ListKrtNaftan = _bussinesEngage.SkipTable(page, initialSizeItem, out recordCount, predicate),
    ...
   }
  };
  ....

Comment: 2)(BLL layer)
  public IEnumerable<T> SkipTable<T>(int page, int initialSizeItem, out long recordCount, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) {
            if (predicate == null) {
                //convert func types
                Expression<Func<krt_Naftan, bool>> func = x => predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x));
 
                return (IEnumerable<T>)Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ScrollLineDTO>>(Engage.GetSkipRows(page, initialSizeItem, out recordCount, x => x.KEYKRT, func));
            }

Comment: public IEnumerable<T> GetSkipRows<T, TKey>(int page, int size, out long recordCount, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderPredicate, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterPredicate = null, bool caсhe = false) where T : class {
            recordCount = GetCountRows(filterPredicate);
            using (Uow = new UnitOfWork()) {
                return Uow.Repository<T>().Get_all(filterPredicate, caсhe).OrderByDescending(orderPredicate).Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size).ToList();
            }
        }

Comment: 3) (DLL layer) get data from db 
        public IQueryable<T> Get_all(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, bool enableDetectChanges = true, bool enableTracking = true) {
            /*//sync data in Db & EF (if change not tracking for EF)
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _dbSet.Where(predicate));
                _context.Entry(_dbSet.Where(predicate)).Reload(); EF 4.1+*/

Comment: In the question itself!

Comment: ActiveContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = enableDetectChanges;
            if (predicate == null) return (enableTracking) ? _dbSet : _dbSet.AsNoTracking();
            var result = (enableTracking) ? _dbSet.Where(predicate) : _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);

            return result;
        }

Comment: At this point I suggest you *delete* this question and post a new one containing all the relevant code. Don't expect anyone to try to reconstruct the code from unformatted comments. Keep in mind that EF expressions get converted to SQL *without* getting executed. That means that `x => x.DTBUHOTCHET == '01.01.2016'` is acceptable. while `x => predicate(Mapper.Map<ScrollLineDTO>(x));` is not

Answer (score 1):

I've found what i needed!

1. [Replace a type in an expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030821/replace-a-type-in-an-expression-tree)
2. [How to change a type in an expression tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932779/how-to-change-a-type-in-an-expression-tree)

Solusion is the Visitor pattern (lINQ have Build-in ExpressionVisitor implementaion (С# 4.0)).

In my case implementaion is:

```
  public static Expression<Func<OutT, bool>> ConvertTypeExpression<inT, OutT>(Expression expression) where OutT : class {

            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(OutT), "x");

            var result = new CustomExpVisitor<OutT>(param).Visit(expression); 

            Expression<Func<OutT, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<OutT, bool>>(result, new[] { param });

            return lambda;
        }

   private class CustomExpVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor {
            ParameterExpression _param;

            public CustomExpVisitor(ParameterExpression param) {
                _param = param;
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
                return _param;
            }

            protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
                if (node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) {
                    MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

                    var memberName = node.Member.Name;
                    var otherMember = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberName);

                    memberExpression = Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), otherMember);

                    return memberExpression;
                } else {
                    return base.VisitMember(node);
                }
            }
        }
```

and in the end i got functionaly that i searched)

```
var filterPredicate = PredicateExtensions.ConvertTypeExpression<ScrollLineDTO, krt_Naftan>(predicate.Body);
```

Comment: How can I adapt this expression to use parameters with different names:
this works:
_visitService.Get(x => x.CustomerId == firstDbVisit.CustomerId)
but this doesn't:
 _visitService.Get(x => x.CustomerId == firstCustomer.Id)
Because parameters' names are different.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for single expressions (x=>x.TypeId=="MyType") but it works in production for some time at this point.

T1 and T2 do not need to be assignable to eachother.

The steps are as follows:
1. Turn the expression into a dictionary
2. Generate an Equals Expression (you can implement other comparisons)

I have pieced these libraries together from various sources over time and cannot remember where they all come from, but here is the primary methods.

```
public class ExpressionHelper
{

    public static IDictionary<string, object> GetMethodParams<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> fromExpression)
    {
        if (fromExpression == null) return null;


        var body = fromExpression.Body as BinaryExpression;
        if (body == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var rVal = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var leftLambda = body.Left as BinaryExpression;
        if (leftLambda != null)
        {
            var params1 = GetExpressionParams(leftLambda);
            foreach (var o in params1) rVal.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
        }
        var rightLambda = body.Right as BinaryExpression;
        if (rightLambda != null)
        {
            var params1 = GetExpressionParams(rightLambda);
            foreach (var o in params1) rVal.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var params1 = GetExpressionParams(body);
            foreach (var o in params1) rVal.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
        }

        return rVal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get Expression Parameters Recursively
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="body"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IDictionary<string, object> GetExpressionParams(BinaryExpression body)
    {
        if (body == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var rVal = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var leftLambda = body.Left as BinaryExpression;
        while (leftLambda != null)
        {
            var params1 = GetExpressionParams(leftLambda);
            foreach (var o in params1) if (!rVal.ContainsKey(o.Key)) rVal.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
            leftLambda = body.Left as BinaryExpression;
        }
        var rightLambda = body.Right as BinaryExpression;
        while (rightLambda != null)
        {
            var params1 = GetExpressionParams(rightLambda);
            foreach (var o in params1) if (!rVal.ContainsKey(o.Key)) rVal.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
            rightLambda = body.Right as BinaryExpression;
        }

        var rightValue = GetValue(body.Right);
        if (rightValue == null)
        {
            var rightSide = body.Right as ConstantExpression;
            if (rightSide != null) rightValue = rightSide.Value;
        }

        var leftSideName = GetMemberName(body.Left);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(leftSideName)) return rVal;
        if (!rVal.ContainsKey(leftSideName)) rVal.Add(leftSideName, rightValue);

        return rVal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get an Equals Expression from the name and value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetEqualExpression<T>(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.Property(p, propertyName);

        Expression propertyExpression = Expression.Call(property, property.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes));

        var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(value?.ToString()));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalsExpression, p);
        return lambda;
    }
}
```

Usage with Items that have the same property StatusId.

```
public class DataReader
{

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get your list via data manager or something
    /// </summary>
    public List<T> ListItems<T>()
        where T : IStatusIdProperty
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }

    public List<T> GetPubItems<T, TView>()
        where T:IStatusIdProperty
        where TView : IStatusIdProperty
    {
        var expression = ConvertExpression<T, TView>(x => x.StatusId == "Pub");
        return ListItems<T>().Where(expression.Compile()).ToList();
    }


    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> ConvertExpression<T, TView>(Expression<Func<TView, bool>> predicate)
        where T : IStatusIdProperty
        where TView : IStatusIdProperty
    {
        var paramDictionary = predicate.GetParamsDictionary().FirstOrDefault();
        var expression = ExpressionHelper.GetEqualExpression<T>(paramDictionary.Key, paramDictionary.Value);
        return expression;
    }

}
```