# Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate two types

Tags: c#

I have WebAPI method:

```
public async Task<MerchantViewModel> Get(string externalId)
    {
        return await _service.Get(m => m.ExternalId == externalId);
    }
```

I have IService:

```
public interface IService<T> 
    where T : class 
{
    Task<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null);
    void Add(T viewModel);
    void Delete(string id);
    void Update(T viewModel);
}
```

And IMerchantService:

```
 public interface IMerchantService : IService<MerchantViewModel>
{
}
```

Implementation with method:

```
  public class MerchantService : IMerchantService { // ... 
public async Task<IEnumerable<MerchantViewModel>> GetAll(Expression<Func<MerchantViewModel, bool>> predicate = null)

.. //
 }
```

Where `T` is `MerchantViewModel`
and I have repository with method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Merchant>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>> predicate = null)
```

Where `T` is `Merchant`.

And now I want to do something like that:

```
public async Task<MerchantViewModel> Get(Expression<Func<MerchantViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    var domainMerchant = this._repository.GetItemAsync(predicate)
}
```

How I can do that?

Merchant and MerchantViewModel have same properties. ViewModel have something more.

Comment: add another overload or pass replace Merchant type with generic T

Comment: Where is `T` in the method signatures? The first two methods return multiple objects. The last method seems to want to return a single object. It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Try to check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

First, abstract the properties that overlap between `MerchantViewModel` and `Merchant` into an interface:

```
public IMerchantFilter
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then let both `MerchantViewModel` and `Merchant` inherit from this interface.

```
public MerchantViewModel : IMerchantFilter
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    ...
}

public Merchant : IMerchantFilter
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Use the interface in the predicate signatures:

```
public class MerchantService : IMerchantService
{
    public Task<MerchantViewModel> Get(Expression<Func<IMerchantFilter, bool>> predicate)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

public class MerchantRepository : ...
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Merchant>> GetItemsAsync(
        Expression<Func<IMerchantFilter, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**Solution 2**

A different solution (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932779/how-to-change-a-type-in-an-expression-tree)) could map predicates between the types:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class PredicateMapper
{
    public static Expression<Func<TTo, bool>> CastParameter<TFrom, TTo>(
        this Expression<Func<TFrom, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo));
        var body = new ParameterReplacer<TTo>(parameter).Visit(predicate.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTo, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    private class ParameterReplacer<TTo> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression parameter;

        public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
        {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return this.parameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var matchingMember = typeof(TTo).GetProperty(node.Member.Name);
            return Expression.Property(this.Visit(node.Expression), matchingMember);
        }
    }
}
```

In your scenario the usage would look as follows:

```
public async Task<MerchantViewModel> Get(
    Expression<Func<MerchantViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    var domainMerchant = this._repository.GetItemAsync(
        predicate.CastParameter<MerchantViewModel, Merchant>());
}
```

See [the working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dl3IjZ) for more details of this implementation.

Be aware that this solution might look nicer in terms of usage but will result in runtime errors instead of compile time errors in case of types that don't match. This makes it in fact more error prone and less maintanable.

Comment: It is good way to do it but what if I have XX classes to do with that way? There are no simple way?

Comment: If this is a common use case then why even have two different models? Why not use `Merchant` and all the other types on both layers?

Comment: Beacause it good pattern to have diferent viewmodel and domain model.. There are small changes between tchem.

Comment: Well another option I see is to have some kind of converter that takes an `Expression<Func<MerchantViewModel, bool>>` and creates an `Expression<Func<Merchant, bool>>` from that. That's probably hard to implement right but very easy to use.

Comment: @Nerf, I updated the answer and added a solution that maps a predicate between the two types. Fortunately it was quite easy.

Comment: For your second method, the name should really be improved.  `MapParameter` would be better, for a start, but even that's not really what's going on here.  `CastParameter` would probably accurately describe what you're doing here.  That said, a simple generic constraint of `where TFrom : TTo` would ensure compile time type safety.  Additionally your `ParameterReplacer` will fail miserably if provided a lambda that has multiple parameters; either the name should reflect this, or it should actually replace a parameter provided.

Comment: `CastParameter` sounds could. Changed it. However there is no inheritance relation between the two types, hence `where TFrom : TTo` wont work. How could `ParameterReplacer` ever get a lamda with more than one parameter? After all, it's a private class used by a function accepting only lambda expression that have a single parameter.