# Convert Expression<Func<T1, bool>> to Expression<Func<T2, bool>>

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am using repository pattern.
T1 is the Dto of T2 (e.x: UserDto and User)

In the service layer, I pass **Expression<Func<UserDto, bool>>**
as a parameter to a method, which in itself calls a method in the data-access layer in which it passes
**Expression<Func<User, bool>>**.

Now, you might ask me why don't I just use **Expression<Func<User, bool>>** all the way but I can't do that.
Is it possible to do the conversion of the Expression?
Note that User and UserDTO have the same props.

Comment: So now that you've added the requirement that you still need to be able to use it with EntityFramework I think this might be the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933106/10608418. Not tested this with EF, but since this doesn't use an untranslatable method call it might just work. Gl with your project!

Comment: Them aim is to use it with EF. That answer looks superb. I will have a deep look at it and reply when I have a conclusion. Thnx

Comment: Where you able to confirm if this works with EF?

Comment: It works for simple expressions. It even mentions it in the answer. It needs to be extended for more complex expr, like x.Child1.Prop etc

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you have a method that converts T2 into T1. Here is a simple toy example where T2 is `string` and T1 is `int`:

```
        // That's the conversion function from T2 to T1
        private static int stringToInt(string s) => s.Length;

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            // We want to convert this into string->bool
            Expression<Func<int, bool>> isEven = i => i % 2 == 0;

            MethodInfo stringToIntMethod = ((Func<string, int>) (stringToInt)).Method;

            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

            // That's the converted expression
            Expression<Func<string, bool>> converted =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
                    Expression.Invoke(isEven,
                        Expression.Call(null, stringToIntMethod, x)), x);

            // Check that it works as expected:
            converted.Compile().Invoke("aa").Should().BeTrue();
            converted.Compile().Invoke("aaa").Should().BeFalse();
        }
```

If you intend to use the expression with a LINQ provider (e.g. Entity Framework or Cosmos DB), you must make sure that the entire expression including the conversion call is supported. This is usually not the case if it is a method that you defined.

If that should be problem, can you impose a common interface or base class on both T1 and T2? In that case you could pass an expression of type `Expression<Func<BaseClass, bool>>` on both layers without conversion. Failing that (e.g. if T1 and T2 are completely different) the only way to achieve what you want is to analyze the structure of the expression and build a custom expression converter (e.g. using `ExpressionVisitor`).

Comment: Thanks. I will take my time to check on that

Comment: Would this new expression still work with adapters that take an `Expression` and translate it to other code? (like EntityFramework). The mention of repository pattern imo gives a strong implication this expression might be used for translation.

Comment: @Knoop No, unless the LINQ provider has built-in support for the conversion method.

Comment: Yes, I intended to use it with EF. Sadly, **The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

Comment: @Ergis That's because there is no way to translate arbitrary custom code (your conversion method) into SQL.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was trynna find out, if It was achievable or not.